# sapply and triple summation

Tags: r, sum, nested-loops, sapply

I have wrote a piece of coding for expression of

```
sum(l(from 1 to n))
       sum(i(from 1 to m))
           sum(t(from 1 to m)
              (phil(i)*phil(t)*[I(X(l)<min(y(i),y(t))-z(i)z(t)]
```

Like this:

```
set.seed(1234567)    
z1<-runif(50,min=0,max=1);m=length(z1)    
z2<-z1;m=length(z1)
x<-rnorm(60);n=length(x)
y<-rnorm(50)*0.25
phil_z1_1<-sqrt(12*(z1/z1))
# using the sapply such that 
sum(sapply(1:n, function(l) {sum(sapply(1:m, function(i){sum(sapply(1:m,function(t){phil_z1_1[i]*phil_z1_1[t]*(x[l]<=min(y(i),y(t))-z[i]*z[t])}))}))
```

Unfortunately this did not work, as i could not get any results after running it

I got something like,

```
sum1<-sum(sapply(1:m, function(t){sum(sapply(1:m, function(i){sum(sapply(1:n,function(l){phil_z1_1[i]*phil_z1_1[t]*(x[l]<=min(y(i),y(t))-z[i]*z[t])}))}))
+
```

I do not understand what the symbol "+" means

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What does the `j` stand for in your sum formula? The "+" indicates a closing bracket is missing. In fact, 2 are missing "})".

Comment: In situations like this, it's a good idea to start small. Write some test code like `sum(sapply(1:4,function(j) sum(sapply(1:3, function(k)k^2))))` to verify you've got the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your formula correctly, you want first determine for which indizes `l,i,t` the expression `min(y[i],y[t])-z[i]*z[t]` is greater or equal to `x[l]`, and then sum
`phil_z1_1[i]*phil_z1_1[t]` over those indizes. Strangely, there is no `l` in latter expression.

Here is one way, but it is probably not the most efficient one:

```
set.seed(1234567)    
z1 <- runif(50,min=0,max=1)
z2 <- runif(50,min=0,max=1)
m <- length(z1)    
x <- rnorm(60)
n <- length(x)
y <- rnorm(50)*0.25
phil_z1_1 <- sqrt(12*(z1/z2))

args <- expand.grid(l=1:n, i=1:m, t=1:m)
args <- subset(args, x[l] <= pmin(y[i],y[t])-z1[i]*z2[t])
args <- transform(args, result=phil_z1_1[i]*phil_z1_1[t])

sum(args[,"result"])
[1] 1173920
```

Note that I renamed some variables, so this may not be what you wanted.

Comment: +1! excellent ! I guess `phil_z1_1 <- sqrt(12*(z1/z2))` not `z1/z1` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful, I had some typos for the previous expression, actually, the expression should be     sum(l(from 1 to n))sum(i(from 1 to m))sum(t(from 1 to m (phil(i)*phil(t)*[I(x(l)<min(y(i),y(t))-z(i)z(t)]